# swift 3 get a substring from query params

Tags: string, swift3

I want to get a substring from a larger string in swift 3. The string is just the query part of a url:

```
user_one_id=7&user_two_id=5
```

I just want the id of each user, so I want 7 and 5.

Comment: Remember, the whole point of types is to offer meaningful abstractions over underlying implementations. Query parameters are stored as strings, yes, but that doesn't mean we need to work on them at that level. In this case, `URLComponents` the abstraction of choice, which makes dealing with query parameters much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quite simple solution is to create `URLComponents`, assign the query part and (flat)map the query items to their values

<strike>`let string = "user_one_id=7&user_two_id=5"
let components = URLComponents(string: "http://dummy.com?" + string)
let userIDs = components?.queryItems?.flatMap{ $0.value }
print(userIDs)`</strike>

```
let string = "user_one_id=7&user_two_id=5"
var components = URLComponents()
components.query = string
let userIDs = components.queryItems!.flatMap{ $0.value }
print(userIDs)
```

Comment: Alternatively `var components = URLComponents() ; components.query = string`, without the need for a dummy scheme+host.

Comment: And you should _never_ teach a beginner to call `URLComponents(string:)` in any case.

Comment: I would suggest `let string = "user_one_id=7&user_two_id=5"; 
var components = URLComponents(); 
components.query = string; 
let userIDs = components.queryItems!.map{$0.value!} // ["7", "5"]`

Comment: @matt: That would crash for `string = "foo&bar=5"` – never teach a beginner for force unwrap :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, guys, I updated the answer with my *safe* version.

Comment: @MartinR Touché

Comment: @vadian Ooooh, I like the formatting with the strikethru. I should do that sort of thing more often.

Comment: Lol this was an entertaining conversation, thanks for all the help!