# Copy part of a string to another string

Tags: ios, swift

I have to parse these type of strings:

```
let result1 = "t=20171017T1201&s=349.00&fn=8712000100030779&i=21456&fp=124519970&n=1"
let result2 = "t=20171016T180757&s=92.00&fn=8710000101140572&i=17711&fp=4191934636&n=1"
```

I need to somehow extract `t` and `fn` parameters and save them to another string:

```
print(t1)    // 20171017T1201
print(fn1)   // 8712000100030779
print(t2)    // 20171016T180757
print(fn2)   // 8710000101140572
```

I managed to get those parameters by checking the whole string symbol by symbol, but there must be a better way to do so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - Get URL Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421686/swift-get-url-parameters).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swift 3 get a substring from query params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46160472/swift-3-get-a-substring-from-query-params).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `components(separatedBy: _)` to split the string into parsable pairs.

```
let result1 = "t=20171017T1201&s=349.00&fn=8712000100030779&i=21456&fp=124519970&n=1"
let result2 = "t=20171016T180757&s=92.00&fn=8710000101140572&i=17711&fp=4191934636&n=1"

func value(for name: String, in query: String) -> String? {
    for params in query.components(separatedBy: "&") {
        let pair = params.components(separatedBy: "=")
        if (pair.first == name) { 
            return pair.last
        }
    }
    return nil
}

print(value(for: "t", in: result1))
print(value(for: "fn", in: result1))
print(value(for: "t", in: result2))
print(value(for: "fn", in: result2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the fact that those strings are basically query parameters of an URL, you can use the following hack to get it quite easily:

```
let result1 = "t=20171017T1201&s=349.00&fn=8712000100030779&i=21456&fp=124519970&n=1"
let result2 = "t=20171016T180757&s=92.00&fn=8710000101140572&i=17711&fp=4191934636&n=1"

let params1 = queryParameters(from: result1)
let params2 = queryParameters(from: result2)

if let t1 = params1["t"], let t2 = params2["t"] {
    print(">>> t1 - \(t1) t2 - \(t2)")
}


public func queryParameters(from parameters: String) -> [String: String] {
    var components = URLComponents()
    components.query = parameters
    guard
        let queryItems = components.queryItems else {
            return [:]
    }

    var parameters = [String: String]()
    for item in queryItems {
        parameters[item.name] = item.value
    }

    return parameters
}
```

Comment: There is no need for a dummy scheme and host, compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/46161342/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR thanks, I've updated the code to reflect it

Answer (score 1):

it would create a little workaround here, `URLComponents` can help to you in this case as your input seems a standard query string to me (see [RFC-3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)).

```
let result1: String = "t=20171017T1201&s=349.00&fn=8712000100030779&i=21456&fp=124519970&n=1"
```

---

so I would take advantages of that and expect working with an array of `URLQueryItem`, so this extension has been placed on an array (maybe not effective but quite straightforward).

```
extension Array where Iterator.Element == URLQueryItem {

    subscript(key: String) -> String? {
        get {
            return self.filter { $0.name == key }.first?.value
        }
    }

}
```

then I would just read the components from a randomly generated but syntactically valid URL in any random order:

```
if let url = URL(string: "u://?\(result1)"),
    let urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) {

    // ...

    let t: String? = urlComponents.queryItems?["t"] // "20171017T1201"
    let s: String? = urlComponents.queryItems?["s"] // "349.00"
    let fp: String? = urlComponents.queryItems?["fp"] // "124519970"
    let random: String? = urlComponents.queryItems?["random"] // nil

    // ...
}
```

---

***NOTE:** this solution is based on the nature of your input string (query-string), if the input format changes in future, you may need to use regular expressions directly to extract information.*

Answer (score 0):

You could implement it like:

```
if let t1 = result1.components(separatedBy: "t=")[1].components(separatedBy: "&").first {
    print(t1) // 20171017T1201
}

if let fn1 = result1.components(separatedBy: "fn=")[1].components(separatedBy: "&").first {
    print(fn1) // 8712000100030779
}
```

**Note** that if you are pretty sure that your string are URL parameters, I would recommend to follow @[Milan Nosáľ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47073700/5501940).